# Change color import globally

Tags: react-native, colors, themes

I use gobally set colors for my react native app by creating `Colors.js` as:

```
export default {   
  primary: 'green',   
  accent: 'red'  
 }
```

And in my compenents I load it with `import Colors from '../Colors.js'`

Now I want a toggle in my settings screen, which changes the global colors in `Color.js`. However, I can't figure it out how. I tried to save a value with react-native-async-storage and then load the colors conditionally, but this won't work in the components.

Is this even possible with react native?

Answer (score 0):

To do so, you have to use a global state such as Redux. Define your color in a store and when you update the store using redux, the whole app will rerender.

Here is the link : https://redux.js.org/

To test it out quickly, you can define a variable on your app.js component and use this.setState to update it.

Comment: Is it possible that this approach only works with inline styles and not styles from the createStylesheet function?

Comment: If you are using CSS you can use SCSS instead or LESS. In SCSS you can define variable for color. like $blue

Comment: CSS is not in use.

Comment: @Heikkisorsa did you find the solution?

Comment: Unfortunately no. Also, I switched to Flutter and so I don't have the problem anymore.